# Jest Mock deleteRecord to throw error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

Is it possible to mock uiRecordApi deleteRecord to throw error?

```
it("should show error toast when delete record method throws error", () => {
        const element = createElement("c-manage", {
            is: manageComp
        });
        
       wireAdapter.emit(mockData);
       const handler = jest.fn();
       element.addEventListener(ShowToastEvent, handler);

        // Act
        document.body.appendChild(element);
  
     
***deleteRecord.error();***
        


        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                //expect
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stub for [uiRecordApi](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/src/lightning-stubs/uiRecordApi/uiRecordApi.js) in sfdx-lwc-jest, you can see the only mock is for the resolved value (success):

```javascript
export const deleteRecord = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();
```

Whereas, for example, `getRecord` provides a wire adapter mock through `createLdsTestWireAdapter`:

```javascript
export const getRecord = createLdsTestWireAdapter(jest.fn());
```

Looking at [wire-service-jest-util](https://github.com/salesforce/wire-service-jest-util), you can see the comment on `createLdsTestWireAdapter`

> Returns a wire adapter mock that mimics Lightning Data Service (LDS)
> adapters behavior, emitted data and error shapes.

It also contains `emit()` and `error()` to mock both resolved and rejected scenarios as you're trying to leverage.

You should be able to copy the provided stub from the repo, but tweak it so you can leverage the ability to have an error occur for `getRecord`

```javascript
export const deleteRecord = createLdsTestWireAdapter(jest.fn());
```

Then, update the `jest.config.js` file to map to your created stub for `uiRecordApi` module

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
        '^lightning/uiRecordApi$':
            '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/yourUiRecordApiStub'
    },
```

Then, you should be able to import your stub of `uiRecordApi` in your jest test and use `deleteRecord.error()` within it.

```javascript
import { deleteRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

...
//in your test method
deleteRecord.error();
```